# Biztalk Administrator groups

Tags: active-directory, biztalk, active-directory-group

Do BizTalk Administrator security groups, namely

```
SSO Administrators               
SSO Affiliate Administrators     
BizTalk Server Administrators
```

really need local administrator right or just administrator right to the SQL server only?

I was challenged by our network administrator regarding rights of the groups and I can not find any Microsoft documents that specifically said the groups need local administrator access.

If such documents exist, I would appreciate it if you can update the link in your answer.

If not, what specific rights do these groups needs? I am not a network admin and is very new to BizTalk, I am not really sure what is needed for BizTalk to operate normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, BizTalk Groups or Users do not need Local Administrator.  In fact, the recommendation is for BizTalk to not run as Administrator, just like most other apps.

However, I have had situations where odd combinations of Policies and other network settings have meant Administrator is needed.

Comment: Got it, John. No wonder I can not find any Microsoft documentation supporting my claims.. :) The wording administrator is quite misleading... :)